# Adding classes dynamically with all its depending libraries in java

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I am trying to provide a plugin storage that every time at the beginning of the code load the plugins jars dynamically from the server . So i provided an interface and and all the plugins implemented this interface.
I am useing currently URLClassLoader and i created simple jar files to test my loader and it worked very well , but when i tested with the real jar files it seem that it didn't load the dependant libraries and gave me

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BrowserCompatSpecFactory.create(Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/cookie/CookieSpec;
```

this method is used in one of the methods of the jars .
Does URLClassloader loades also the required libraries ?
PS : The jar itself is tested from the terminal and its running well so the problem properly in the loader.

Answer (score 0):

`URLClassloader` loads classes as and when required.
I suspect that in your case `URLClassloader` is loading incorrect version of dependent classes, pay attentio to `NoSuchMethodError` - it indicates that the class **is** loaded but it does not have a method definition.

Comment: actually my method which i invoked didn't give exception but this exception is thrown because the method in the plugin invoke such method from an imported library . I also tried to import this library in my referenced libraries but did not help.